# Ubuntu: tomcat starts on terminal but not running on browser?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04, http-proxy

I have installed tomcat 7 and jdk 7 on my ubuntu 12.0 machine. Though it has been properly installed as when I use startup.sh command it shows me on terminal the path of :

CATALINA_BASE CATALINA_HOME JRE_HOME CLASSPATH

But when I run it on localhost:8080 or `http://127.0.0.1:8080` it shows page not found.

To avoid this I have added the proxy settings in my mozilla browser but still it shows page not found.Is there anything else remaining that I can try upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the STDOUT output of your tomcat process. It is usually named catalina.out. You can do this quickly by running as the same user as tomcat:

```
less  /proc/$(pgrep -f tomcat)/fd/1
```

Check also if tomcat is indeed listening on port 8080:

```
sudo netstat -tlnp |grep java
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if there the 8080 port is free (that is not being used by another service). And then if you have set up correctly the CATALINA_HOME path.

If you have GUI on your machine you could use NetBeans with pre-installed Apache Tomcat. It's very easy to launch tomcat from NetBeans and you can easily manage whole server from there.

Link for NetBeans:

[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=javaee)